# Spring MVC with Hibernate Validator Mandatory for the database field, but not in the application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

Problem with `BindingResult` `hasErrors()` in validation.
I have this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/entity", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String submit(@Valid @ModelAttribute Entity entity, BindingResult result) {
  Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  entity.setCreatedBy(auth.getName());
  if (result.hasErrors()) {
     //Here the error of createdBy is null
     return "entity/new";
  } else {
     entityService.save(entity);
     return "redirect:/entity/list";
  }
}
```

the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_X")
public class Entity implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "primary_key")
   private String primaryKey;
   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "created_by")
   private String createdBy;
   //getters and setter
}
```

I need set the value of `createdBy` in controller but always show "may not be null" in view.
Please help.

*Spring MVC 4*, *Hibernate Validator 5*, *Database Oracle 11g*

Comment: Could you please provide more details? You can set the value in controller and you can always show message on view, so what's the problem?

Comment: The BindingResult not know of entity.setCreatedBy(auth.getName()); and result.hasErrors() is true, so the object Entity is not saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `entity` object is validated before Spring MVC invokes the `submit()` method. The `result` object is created at the same time. This line:

```
entity.setCreatedBy(auth.getName());
```

has absolutely no effect on the outcome of `result.hasErrors()`.

Comment: Why do you need to validate the `createdBy` field if it is not a user input (but a value supplied by your code)? You could remove `@NotNull` from `createdBy`.